# How to solve this using definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, area

I already have asked $2$ questions on similar topics. In that questions I have equations of parabola and line. And equations have $y$ and $x$ variable.

But in this question I have functions.

$$f(x) = |x| - 1 \quad\mbox{and}\quad g(x) = 1 - |x|.$$

a) Sketch their graphs.

b) Using integration find the area of the bounded region.

In other two questions I know how to find values of $x$ and $y$ using substitution. But in this question because of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I am clueless how to start.

Please provide answer in detail.

My attempt is only.

$f(x) = x - 1, -x - 1$

$g(x) = 1 - x, 1 + x$.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9sho5r7uue

Comment: But how to find value of y as we have no y variable in equation.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nlrqqou8bf

Comment: y=f (x) and y=g (x)

Comment: So you can write y=|x|-1 and y=1-|x| . Does that help ease the confusion or this is not what you meant about the confusion on f and g?

Comment: @John Sr Maybe you have to sketch first the graphs and from there you will see that they intersect at the points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: But it is not given f(x) = g(x).

Comment: I'm not saying f=g.

Comment: The y-coordinates of a function f can be produced by plugging in values of x into f (x). Same for g (x).

Comment: http://statisticslectures.com/topics/functionnotation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presumed you know how to sketch the region. Then
$$A=2\int_{0}^1[(1-x)-(x-1)]dx=\int_0^1(4-4x)dx=2.$$

In set notation, the region $R$ is given by
$$R=\{(x,y):-1\leq x\leq 1,f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)\}.$$
The line $x=0$ or known as the $y$-axis serves the line of symmetry.

Okay,this is the [graph](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/?panel-102-graph&data-bounds-xMin=-10&data-bounds-xMax=10&data-bounds-yMin=-7.28&data-bounds-yMax=7.28&data-equations-0=%22y%3D1%20-%20abs(x)%20%22&data-equations-1=%22y%3Dabs(x)-1%22&data-rand=undefined&data-hideGrid=false) of the region $R$.

Comment: @John Sr Feel free to ask--:D

Comment: Your answer is wrong. In book its 2. And I have main problem in drawing sketch. Because we have no y variable.

Comment: @John Sr Why is it wrong? Try to simplify my answer and the answer is 2. You want the solution?

Comment: I want explanation for how to draw graph. Please help me.

Comment: @John Sr To find the points of intersection, we get $$1-|x|=|x|-1$$ and yields $|x|=1$ implying that $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Thus, their points of intersection are $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: @John Sr I included in my solution the graph of the region $R$.

Comment: Can we write f(x) = g(x) = y?

Comment: @John Sr Yes you are correct, as long as we assume that $(x,y)$ is their point of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for f (x) shift the graph of $|x|$ by 1  towards right. For other function use $g (x)=1+x $ when x is negative and $1-x $ for positive. Then find the intersection with $f (x) $and then the area

Comment: How to find coordinate for graph? And how to find coordinate for y variable?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when finding area we do $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)-g(x)\text{d}x$ where f is the "top" function along the interval. So looking at a sketch of the region g(x) is on top over the interval and the interval is from -1 to 1. So our integral is $\int_{-1}^{1}1-\left | x\right |-(\left | x \right |-1)\text{d}x=$ $\int_{-1}^{1} 2-2\left |x\right |\text{d}x$ intuitively we can see that $\int \left | x\right |\text{d}x=\frac{\left |x\right |x}{2}+C$ from the piecewise definition of $|x|$ so using this just makes the integral into a pretty standard definite integral. I personally prefer this way because you do not need to figure out where the sign changes and do multiple integrals. However this only works for absolute value functions in the form $\left |ax+b\right |$ with higher powers and other functions you do need multiple integrals. Hope this helps a bit